# python comtypes how to pass numpy float32 (singe-precision float) as scalar?

Tags: python, numpy, com, cython, pywin32

According to comtypes documentation is is possible to pass numpy arrays to comtypes objects, but how to I pass scalar values, e.g. `numpy.float32(1.0)`?

https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/#numpy-interop

I get following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-9e7e5859c6a5> in <module>()
----> 1 com_obj.Update("string_name",np.float32(6.6e-6))
ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Cannot put 6.5999998e-06 in VARIANT
```

Comment: https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/issues/86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `ctypes.c_float` rather than `np.float32` will work. e.g. `com_obj.Update("string_name", ctypes.c_float(6.6e-6))`.

Comment: you also mentioned ctypes.c_float

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've changed my response to refer to `ctypes.c_float` instead of `cython.float`.